# How can an astroid be filldrawn in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I was wondering how the following astroid could be filldrawn in tikz.

```
x^(2/3)+y^(2/3)=(56/3\pi)^(1/3)
```

[image]

Comment: 1st step. Use a parametric equation rather than an implicit one. See [this page](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Equation_of_Astroid/Parametric_Form) for example.

Comment: It seems that you persist on asking the same question again. This one is not different from the others, you may take advantage in learning from the answers you received already, and try it by yourself, don't you think?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={ fun(\x) =  ((56/3*pi)^(1/3)-\x^(2/3))^(3/2); }]
\filldraw[red, ultra thick, fill=pink, samples=100, smooth, domain=0:(56/3*pi)^(1/2)]
   plot (\x, {fun(\x)} ) -- plot ({fun(\x)}, -\x ) -- plot (-\x, {-fun(\x)} ) -- plot ({-fun(\x)}, \x ) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Pink diamond]